# Array of column Letters to Array of Column Numbers not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is more or less my first attempt at writing a Javascript function and I want to convert an array of column numbers to an array of column letters

If I run testFunction I get `undefined`

```
function testFunction() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

   aryCLTCN(["A","C","D"])

   ui.alert(aryCLTCN[3]);
}

function aryCLTCN(array) {
  var columnLet = array
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0, length = columnLet.length; i < length; i++) {
    output[i] = [];
    output[i] = CLTCN(columnLet[(i)]);
    }
}

function CLTCN(letter)
{
  var column = 0, length = letter.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    column += (letter.charCodeAt(i) - 64) * Math.pow(26, length - i - 1);
  }
  return column;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

Within `function testFunction()` you call `aryCLTCN(["A","C","D"])` but don't assign the result to a variable, then with `aryCLTCN[3]` you are trying to access a property "3" of the function itself. Which isn't a syntax error because functions can have properties, but the function has no such property so you get `undefined`. You need something like this:

```
var result = aryCLTCN(["A","C","D"]);
ui.alert(result[3]);
```

Except note that JavaScript arrays are zero-based, which means that `[3]` tries to access the *fourth* element, but your array only has three elements.

Within `function aryCLTCN(array)` you create an `output` array but don't return it. You need to add `return output;`.

Also with these two lines:

```
    output[i] = [];
    output[i] = CLTCN(columnLet[(i)]);
```

...the first line assigns `output[i]` to a new empty array, but the second line overwrites that with the return value from `CLTCN(columnLet[(i)]);`. You can remove `output[i] = [];`.

Putting all that together:

```js
function testFunction() {
  // var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // commented out for demo in browser

  var result = aryCLTCN(["A","C","D"])

  // using alert() instead of ui.alert() for demo here in browser
  alert(result[3]); // undefined because there's no 4th element
  alert(result[2]); // shows third element
}

function aryCLTCN(array) {
  var columnLet = array
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0, length = columnLet.length; i < length; i++) {
    output[i] = CLTCN(columnLet[(i)]);
  }
  return output;
}

function CLTCN(letter)
{
  var column = 0, length = letter.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    column += (letter.charCodeAt(i) - 64) * Math.pow(26, length - i - 1);
  }
  return column;
}

testFunction();
```

(Note that for the purposes of having a runnable code snippet in my answer I'm using `alert()` instead of `ui.alert()`, but in your real code you would stick with `ui.alert()`.)

Comment: Thanks nnnnn, helpful commentary, I understand better!

Answer (score 1):

You get an undefined error because you are calling the trying to access an index on a function. `aryCLTCN` function needs to have a return the `output` array and you need to assign it to a variable in your `testFunction` to be able to access its elements.

Although there was nothing logically or effectively wrong with your functions, I have provided another working solution below.

```
function testFunction() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var colArr = ["A", "B", "Z", "AA", "AZ", "ZA", "AAA"];
  var nColArr = colArr.map(function(col) { 
    var colNum = 0;
    col.split('').forEach(function(l, i) { colNum += (l.charCodeAt() - 64) * Math.pow(26, col.length - 1 - i) }); 
    return colNum;
  });

  ui.alert(nColArr); //Shows all elements inside the  nColArr array.
  ui.alert(nColArr[3]); //Shows the 4th element inside the nColArr array.
}
```

Try it out:

```js
var colArr = ["A", "B", "Z", "AA", "AZ", "ZA", "AAA"];
var nColArr = colArr.map(function(col) {
  var colNum = 0;
  col.split('').forEach(function(l, i) {
    colNum += (l.charCodeAt() - 64) * Math.pow(26, col.length - 1 - i)
  });
  return colNum;
});
console.log(nColArr);
```

Comment: *"You get an undefined error"* - It's not an *error* in the sense of a syntax error or exception, it's just that `someFunc[3]` gives the value `undefined`.

Comment: Well, an error is a mistake and in this case it was a user error.